# Enabling FrameRate Counter for Windows Phone globally for default applications

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to compare the FPS between phones from diffrent manufacturers. I will be using default phone applications such as `Contacts.exe`, Browser and SMS applications. I read from the forum that there is setting to enable the `FrameRateCounter` widget which application developer can enable to measure FPS for his application.

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

But since all applications that I am trying to use for performance measurement are default (no source code), can we enable this feature globally and check FPS for any application that we launch globally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to activate this setting on a global scale. To benchmark different phones, you'll probably have to make your own multi-purpose app to test the scenarios you're interested in. Note that there's already a few benchmark apps available on the MarketPlace.

As a side note, `Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter` is a Silverlight setting, while `Contacts.exe` is a native app. So even if there was a way to activate the setting globally, it wouldn't work for this specific app.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. Yeah I am planning have my own applicaiton that tests various scenarios. Can you give market place application names that do similar performance test on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Also I am looking for app launch timing calculator. Is it possible by some means to calculate the application launch timings? Again how can we use this method on default applications? Native/Managed? Any way to log the timings?